# Django: is there a generic handler to insert a POST object directly into the database?

Tags: ajax, django, rest, django-generic-views

Django: is there a generic handler to insert a POST object directly into the database?  I find myself writing a lot of handlers that look like this.

```
def ajax_storeObject(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         Object(
                field1 = request.POST["field1"],
                field2 = request.POST["field2"],
                field3 = request.POST["field3"],
                field4 = request.POST["field4"],
          ).save()
          return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status":"Success"}), mimetype="application/json")
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status":"Failed"}), mimetype="application/json")
```

It seems like there could be a one-line generic view to take care of this kind of thing.  Does such a view exist?

Edit: BTW, I'm comfortable with model forms, but the use case I'm looking at here is more narrow: RESTful AJAX calls that aren't based on standard forms (e.g. the user manipulates an object on the page, and a REST call is sent to notify the server.).

Comment: You might want to consider [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about forms that requires you to actually draw a form.  ModelForms are the right thing to use if you're not going to go with piston or tastypie or something like that.

Put this in your page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

```
class ObjectAjaxForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
     model = Object
     fields = ("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4")


#or, if you don't want the "free" csrf protection
#@csrf_exempt
def ajax_store_object(request):
    #request.POST can be substituted with any dictionary/dictionary like object
    form = ObjectAjaxForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status":"Success"}), mimetype="application/json")
    else:
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status":"Failed"}), mimetype="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)?

Comment: Ah, good point. I understand model forms. The use case I'm looking at here is more narrow: RESTful AJAX calls that aren't based on standard forms (e.g. the user manipulates an object on the page, and a REST call is sent to notify the server.).  I've edited the question to reflect this scope.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no generic Ajax view, but perhaps you are looking for this?

```
Object(**request.POST).create()
```

Of course, you need to make sure `request.POST` doesn't contain anything you don't want to put in the model (like a "submit" field).

Comment: I see why modelForms work here, but just out of curiosity, what's wrong with this?

Comment: If I know you're doing this, I can easily construct a malicious form where i include id="abcdsef", or id=999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999. Alternately, if you later add non-public fields to your model (i.e. _reputation_sum), malicious actors could give themselves infinity reputation.  If you've got a foreign key, I could spam all your users by overriding user_id.  And that's just the potential exploits I can come up with in five minutes.  Explicit is better than implicit.